# Knockout populating table with sqlalchemy query

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask, knockout.js

I posted a question previously and the response linked to a question that did not help and the problem has since evolved so here is a new question
This is the entirety of my HTML file that i am using to post the results of a query to my database. the query works correctly and it returns the json information like it should however im not sure how to take the json from the response and populate the table without reloading the page. currently what happens is i fill in the table to query the database, the results are then serialized to json and the page then displays the json information.(this is all handled by my flask route declaration.) What i want to accomplish is no reload instead it just populates the table with the results in the proper field

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reports</title>
</head>
<body>
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="index">
    <h1>Report Generation</h1>
      <p>Search for accounts to generate a report for.</p>
<div class="jumbotron">
        <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="query">
        <label for="searchFirst" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
            <input type="name" value="{{request.form.searchFirst}}" name="searchFirst" id="searchFirst" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
        <label for="searchLast" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
            <input type="name" value="{{request.form.searchLast}}" name="searchLast" id="searchLast" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
        <label for="searchPhone" class="sr-only">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="name" value="{{request.form.searchPhone}}" name="searchPhone" id="searchPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
               <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    <br>
      <div id="results">
                <table class="blueTable" id="queries">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Policy(ies) ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Street</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Zip Code</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-bind="foreach: viewModel.queries">
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: first"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: last"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: street"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: city"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: state"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: zipcode"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: phonenumber"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
      </div>

  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
     ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
     viewModel.loadQueries()
});

    function result(result){
        this.id = ko.observable(result.id);
        this.first = ko.observable(result.first);
        this.last = ko.observable(result.last);
        this.street = ko.observable(result.street);
        this.city = ko.observable(result.city);
        this.state = ko.observable(result.state);
        this.zipcode = ko.observable(result.zipcode);
        this.phonenumber = ko.observable(result.phonenumber);
    }

    var viewModel = {
    queries: ko.observableArray([]),
    loadQueries: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON("/process",function (queries) {
                self.queries.removeAll();
                self.queries(queries)
            }
        );
    }
};

    $('#query').submit(function (e) {
       $.postJSON('/reports', query, result());
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery.extend({
      postJSON: function(url, data, callback) {
        return jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/reports',
          data: typeof data == 'string'?data:JSON.stringify(data),
          success: callback,
          dataType: url,
          contentType: "application/json",
          processData: false
        });
      }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

This is how my json gets returned

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "city": "your city", 
      "first": "No", 
      "id": 6, 
      "last": "Policy", 
      "phonenumber": "0000000000", 
      "state": "your state", 
      "street": "123 Main St", 
      "zipcode": "00000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to change your `foreach` binding to `foreach: queries`.The reload part is not clear. You want to refresh the data after `$.postJSON('/reports')` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript block you need to define what your callback function needs to be. You use it as an argument to your post function, but my guess is that it is currently undefined. This is the function that gets called upon success in ajax communication.

E.g.

```
function callback(data) {
    // do something here
}

$('#query').submit(function (e) {
   $.postJSON('/reports', query, result());
    e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery.extend({
  postJSON: function(url, data, callback) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/reports',
      data: typeof data == 'string'?data:JSON.stringify(data),
      success: callback,
      dataType: url,
      contentType: "application/json",
      processData: false
    });
  }
```